# Vue.js import Axios within method then use it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have got a component which might not request an ajax call if some data has been passed into it. However if the data hasn't been passed in I need to fetch it, so I want to import Axios then, save importing it for no reason.

How can I wait for the script to be imported before attempting to use it, as the below doesn't work:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        vehicleId: {
            type: Number|String,
            required: true,
            default: () => null
        },
        settings: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => null
        }
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        if (!this.settings) {
            const Axios = () => import('../../../axiosConfig');

            Axios.get('/api/v1/media-slider-settings').then(response => {
                this.settings = response.data;
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: Why that doesn't work? Is there any error in the console? Are you using any build system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic `import` return a Promise, so you must to use `then` function.

Try something like that:

```html
<script>
export default {
  beforeCreate() {
    if (!this.settings) {
      import('../../../axiosConfig').then(axios => {
        axios.get('/api/v1/media-slider-settings').then(response => {
          this.settings = response.data;
        });
      });
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Avoid the approach with `async/await` because the lifecycle functions don't support asynchronous in Vue.js.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, `import()` is async, so just do:

```js
// or use .then if you're not in an async function
const Axios = (await import('../../../axiosConfig')).default

Axios.get('/api/v1/media-slider-settings').then(response => {
  this.settings = response.data;
});
```

and notice that `import()` returns the module, so you need to get the `.default` property if you need the default export (like in your case) or just call `.someExportedName` for importing a named export (i.e. non-default export from the module)